# Cannot resolve setAdapter and setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android

I am not able to resolve setAdapter and setOnItemSelectedListener. Can anyone solve the problem.

Cannot resolve setAdapter and setOnItemSelectedListener

```
public class Spinner extends AppCompatActivity{

private ArrayList<CountryItem> mCountryList;
private CountryAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spinner);

    initList();

    Spinner spinnerCountries = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_countries);

    mAdapter = new CountryAdapter(this, mCountryList);
    spinnerCountries.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    spinnerCountries.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CountryItem clickedItem = (CountryItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String clickedCountryName = clickedItem.getCountryName();
            Toast.makeText(Spinner.this, clickedCountryName + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}

private void initList() {
    mCountryList = new ArrayList<>();
    mCountryList.add(new CountryItem("India", R.drawable.app_logo));
    mCountryList.add(new CountryItem("China", R.drawable.app_logo));
    mCountryList.add(new CountryItem("USA", R.drawable.app_logo));
    mCountryList.add(new CountryItem("Germany", R.drawable.app_logo));
}
```

Comment: try Build- Clean Project

Answer (score 0):

Its the same class name 'Spinner' same  as the widget - Spinner  that may  be the cause of the issue,  make sure  u have imported the widget Spinner correctly, like-:

```
import android.widget.Spinner;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your own class name from `Spinner` to `SpinnerActivity`. There's a simple conflict between your class and `android.widget.Spinner`